# how to retrieve python json object value

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the value for each object in an array, in javascript like person.name, person.type.

but in python how would I implement it ?

```
schema_array = [
    { 'name': 'season', 'type':'VARCHAR' },
    { 'name': 'name', 'type':'VARCHAR' },
    { 'name': 'apperances', 'type':'INT' },
    { 'name': 'starts', 'type':'INT' },
    { 'name': 'minutes', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'assist', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'steal', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'block', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'score', 'type':'FLOAT' }
]

table_schema = '';
for x in schema_array:
  print( x )
  # x.name , x.type doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array or actually python `list` in this case contains dictionaries. A dictionary consists of a key:value pair. To access the value you can do 2 things. Either use `yourdictionaryname["key"]` (which crashes if there is no value for your key in the dictionary) or `yourdictionaryname.get("key", "not found")` which allows you to specify a value to return in case the key has no value in the dictionary.

```
schema_array = [
    { 'name': 'season', 'type':'VARCHAR' },
    { 'name': 'name', 'type':'VARCHAR' },
    { 'name': 'apperances', 'type':'INT' },
    { 'name': 'starts', 'type':'INT' },
    { 'name': 'minutes', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'assist', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'steal', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'block', 'type':'FLOAT' },
    { 'name': 'score', 'type':'FLOAT' }
]

table_schema = '';
for x in schema_array:
  print(x["name"], x["type"])
  print("Alternatively")
  print(x.get("name"), x.get("type"))
```